# Coin-operated arcade quiz game with a touchscreen

Tags: identify-this-game

In the game rooms with the usually coin-ops there was a "game" which use touch-screen (!) and you have to answer correctly to some quiz about culture, for example: Which is the capital of France? In what year was created the first airplane?..., etc. Unfortunately I have no picture of it, and I don't know the name.

I remind:

- For every question there is A B C D choices
- When you found the correct answer you touch A or B or C on screen
- There was background pics for every question
- There was a "cumulative timeout"
- Screen was 4/3
- In the years between 2003-2007 this "game" was retired, I never found it in any game-room

Comment: I think there's no single answer to this.  Trivia machines were commonplace, especially in bars.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think I would call that culture, more general knowledge. The capital of France is Paris, regardless of whether French people love their freedom, or distrust right-wing zealots, or appreciate it when foreigners even *try* to speak their language (however badly) :-) Big shout out to all the lovely French shop-keepers who helped me out in that, BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be this one ??

Photo Play

[image: Photoplay machine]

Comment: Is it, thanks,another proof is that was developed in Italy. I play it in a tourist ship in Italy, over 19y ago!

Comment: @elbarna - there's a German Wikipedia article [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_Play) which suggests the developer was actually Austrian.

Comment: Thanks for information, probably was developed by austrian and then distributed in italian version, as I know there are english, german, spanish and french version of it.